# Header to accomodate product IDs with 2 different lengths

Tags: gui-design

I have to display the ID of some products, there are 2 kind of product ID, one with 18 characters and the other one with 7 characters.

The double vertical bar between the ID and the  is a visible vertical bar.

I'm not sure which would be the best solution.

In my application, there is a big "distance" between each product line, so they are not  always visible.

```
| product : 1234567890ABCDEFGH || <product icon> | Product Category : XYZ | <other info> |

| product : 1234567 || <product icon> | Product Category : XYZ |  <other info> |
```

or (with not fixed width for the product )

| product : 1234567 ||  | Product Category : XYZ |   |

or (with fixed width for the product)

```
| product : 1234567890ABCDEFGH || <product icon> | Product Category : XYZ | <other info> |

| product : 1234567            || <product icon> | Product Category : XYZ |  <other info> |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the full details of your use case, but one thing is that it seems possible to cut down on repetitive elements to increase legibility.

Rather than repeating the labels and using || to separate elements, try using a tabular view, but without borders and pipe elements, and use alignment with a fixed width so users can scan and compare the two values under each label. . You can make these fairly small to fit into a tight space:

[image]

You can set the width to accommodate the max ID, and then when you have 2 IDs they stack for legibility. Let me know if there are other constraints and I'll try to address them.

Comment: Thanks, I did put too in too much, I don't have that much repetition.

I think the fixed width will be the primary choice.